# Footable error after upgrading to latest version of jQuery

Tags: jquery, footable

Everything was working great! Then I upgraded to latest version of jQuery. 3.4.1. I am using my own custom UI for footable filtering. The code that is giving me the issue is:

```
        $('#<%= ListViewContainer.ClientID%>.footable-container.list-view 
         table').each(function () {
            tables.push(FooTable.get($(this).footable()));

        });
```

When using older version of jQuery, the tables array returns all the footables as a FooTable object. But when using the latest jQuery, tables array returns undefined.

Comment: What version did you use before?

Comment: jQuery version: 2.2.4

Comment: Do you have Bootstrap 3.3.6 or lower as well? Chances are you'll need to upgrade this to 3.3.7.

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3.3.7